# Why Drawable background disappears in large Views?

Tags: java, android, view

I have a problem and I really do not know what's going on.

It is the following, I have a drawable.xml as background of a textview that is element of a listview, I set it and everything OK but I have the action that when they touch it expands (changing the number of visible lines), at that moment it is that the background is lost. Its happens only in very large views

Before it was done with background images.9 and it worked well

Here are the elements mentioned and a picture :D
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wIaX.jpg)

```html
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wIaX.jpg" alt="Sample" height="50%" width="50%">
```

Regards

fondo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp">
<solid android:color="@color/mailUnReadBack" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Activity.java

```
...
private void expand(View view) {
   ((TextView) view).setMaxLines(reduceLines?minVal: Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
...
```

myView.java

```
...
setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fondo));
...
```

Comment: by the way is the same text

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe set background again after expanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

**drawable/fondo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <padding
       android:bottom="5dp"
       android:top="5dp"
       android:right="25dp"
       android:left="25dp">

    <solid android:color="@color/mailUnReadBack" />

    <corners
      android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

**Java**

```
Drawable background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.fondo);
ViewCompat.setBackground(yourView, background);
```